# Find numbers of seperated chunks in 2d file from file Python

Tags: python, file

Sorry in advance if the title was a bit confusing, not sure how to word it better

In python, if you were to have a seperate 'file.txt' containing the following text:

`.....%%%%%..%
%%%...%%...%%
%.....%%%..%%
...%%.....%%%
....%%.....%%
.....%%%..%%%
%%%%....%%%..`

Representing splatters of paint, I'm trying to find a way to output the number of individual chunks, in this case this would return '4', I'm having trouble visualising how I would go about doing this, any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are those chunks? Can't see that "4" in there.

Comment: I believe that it counts as a chunk, if there is another item one space away from it, either vertically, horizontally or diagonally

Comment: And item is a dot? not "%"?

Comment: yes, the '.' is essentially an area with nothing

Comment: Did my solution help you? I can improve it if you clarify the chunk notion and add some more details.

Comment: Yes, the solution helped, thankyou very much

Comment: That's great, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what is a "chunk" but this assumes that it's a cluster of `%` elements:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

pattern = [];
with open('patterns.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('%','1').replace('.','0').replace('',' ')
        pattern.append((line.strip(' \n ')).split())

image = np.array(pattern, dtype = int)

pstruct = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
labeled_array, num_features = ndimage.measurements.label(image,structure = pstruct)
```

This program reads your input file of `.` and `%` into a nested list. It turns all `%` to 1 and `.` to 0 and generates a `numpy` array of integers with 1 and 0 representing your original pattern. It then uses a `scipy` function to look for clusters of 1s.

`pstruct` defines what is considered a cluster, and when the default is used it produces 5 chunks, for details look here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html.

`labeled_array` are chunks numbered by their cluster number and `num_features` is the number of clusters.

If this does not properly define your chunk, clarify it a bit more or even better - upload an image where you explicitly mark the chunks.